# How can I put multiple QR codes in MS word?

Tags: excel, label

I'm a teacher and running coach, and I could really use your help. I am trying to use data in an Excel format (columns of runner name, school, grade, and a link to a QR generator that uses that same information to generate a URL of an image of that specific QR code. [See here for example.](http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=350x350&chl=MECARD%3aN%3aCharles%20Adams;ORG%3aXYZ%20Co.;TEL:123456789;EMAIL%3aca@xyz.com;ADR:88%20Broad%20Street,%20New%20York,%20NY%2010004,%20USA;URL%3ahttp://www.xyz.com;NOTE%3achadams%20in%20twitter;;)). This would feed into a mail merge for labels in MS Word.

The end product I'm looking for is a set of Avery labels with runner name, school, and a QR code. This way, each runner wears a specific label, and after they cross the finish line in a race, I can scan in their information with a QR code app on my phone.

This would also have many uses for many of the teachers at my school: we could keep track of student items such as paperback books, folders, and assignments with these QR codes.

Thank you kindly for any help you can provide!

Best,

Dave

Comment: Which aspect exactly are you looking for advice on? Generating the QR Code? Or saving the unique QR code? Or something else?

Comment: Hi Caitriona, thanks for your question. I'm looking for advice on saving the unique QR code into the MS Word file for printing. I can get the URL of the QR Code image to display in MS Word from a mail merge, but not the image itself. I've found out how to generate multiple QR codes already.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for answering my question!   I appreciate you giving me a clue to the puzzle.

**Here's what I did**:  [Here's the website I used.](http://qrexplore.com/generate/).
After getting the `.png` files, I was able to print them onto label paper (which I had to chop up myself) in groups of 9's from the Windows print picture function when viewing a folder. `Lo` and `behold`, each kid gets a `QR code` with the information printed below it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use one of the online QR Code generators like www.qrstuff.com and download the image of each QR code you generate and then set up a Word document with a template for the label sheets you are using (Avery sheets for instance which Word has templates for) and then import the QR Code Images you downloaded into the template and print.